# Android ClassCastException Lists cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments, casting

I have seen this question on here, but non solved my issue. My fragments extend a class called `CommonListFragment` that extends the Fragment class . My Activity that hosts the fragments extends a class called `CommonActivity` that extends `FragmentActivity` class. Everything seems to be ok, so why the following error?

> Android `ClassCastException` Lists cannot be cast to `android.app.Fragment`

**So as you can see above, Android is trying to cast my List class to `android.app.Fragment` when it should really be casting to android.support.v4.app.Fragment.   My List class ultimately extends the Fragment class (android.support.v4.app.Fragment). Also my minimum and target SDK is Android 2.2. so if I try to import  'android.app.Fragment' there are compiler errors. So how can I force Android to recognize my List as a android.support.v4.app.Fragment?**

`CommonActivity.java`:

```
public class CommonActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
}
```

`ListsContainer.java`:

```
public class ListsContainer extends CommonActivity implements OnListChangedListener {

    private int m_orientation ;
    private static int EXTRA_LARGE = 4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_ctx = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.lists_container);
    ...
```

`CommonListFragment`:

```
 public class CommonListFragment extends Fragment implements  IOnEditTextClickedListener,
                                                                 IOnItemCheckedListener,
                                                                 IOnDismissDialog,
                                                                 ISettings,
                                                                 OnClickListener
{
        public void onItemChecked(int pos,boolean checked,String sGroup,String sList){

        }
        ...
}
```

`lists_container.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.onesix.myApp.Lists" ></fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.onesix.myApp.List" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
08-06 00:15:44.228: W/ServerManagedPolicy(7472): Licence retry count (GR) missing, grace period disabled
08-06 00:17:35.207: W/dalvikvm(7472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41814970)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.onesix.myApp/com.onesix.myApp.ListsContainer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:339)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at com.onesix.myApp.ListsContainer.onCreate(ListsContainer.java:18)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     ... 11 more
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.onesix.myApp.Lists cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4800)
08-06 00:17:35.287: E/AndroidRuntime(7472):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

`List.java`:

```
public class List extends CommonListFragment implements IOnDismissYesNoListener
{

    @Override
    public View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle  savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //setContentView(R.layout.list);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,container, false);
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }

    ...
}
```

LATEST LOGCAT

```
08-06 01:05:00.736: E/AndroidRuntime(15588): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.onesix.myApp.Lists cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
08-06 01:05:00.736: E/AndroidRuntime(15588):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617)
08-06 01:05:00.736: E/AndroidRuntime(15588):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
08-06 01:05:00.736: E/AndroidRuntime(15588):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4800)
08-06 01:05:00.736: E/AndroidRuntime(15588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

Anyone have any ideas? I have checked every question about this topic on SO...

Comment: i think you should also provide stack trace

Comment: @mmlooloo: Logcat added

Comment: do you have still problem, i have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
class="com.onesix.myApp.List"
```

In your class `List` you are importing support library's fragment instead of default fragment of android that is because you are using `FragmentActivity` means you must use the fragment from the non-support library.

make sure that all your **fragment class** specially in your `List class` import this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

EDIT:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.onesix.myApp.List" >
    <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
</fragment>
```

Comment: My minimum SDK is Android 2.2 so the android.app.Fragment class in not available only android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: @Mike then make sure that you are importing `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: I added trace and Lists class

Comment: @Mike your classes are good, try to change the class declaration to xml, instead of `class="com.onesix.myApp.List"` use `android:name`

Comment: " change class declaration" to xml ? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Mike from `class= . . .` to `android:name= . . .` see my above editted code

Comment: I didn't work --- trying to get logcat but having some issues with it right now...

Comment: @Mike any other activity that uses lists_container?? or make sure that all imports has `v4.support` even for `fragment transactions`

Comment: I posted my latest logcat and yes all fragments use v4.support  ---they have to otherwise compiler error s because my minimum is 2.2.   hmmmm..just can't figure it.